# HTML not changing font style when using CSS

Tags: html, css

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Single Column</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="single.css>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <h2>Here's some content</h2>
    <p>This is where a story would go</p>
    <h2>Here's more content</h2>
    <p>This is another story</p>
</div> <!-- end content -->
</div> <!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>`
```

The code above is my HTML file and the code below is my css file. when i open the browser and search local host it displays the content but the font is not changing?

```
body
{
font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}

#container
{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
background: #FFFFFF;
}

#content
{
clear: left;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Closed as simple typographical error

Comment: This is not useful to people moving forward, please delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the closing quote in your link `href` for css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="single.css">
                                                      ^^ missing quote
```

Comment: Wow how silly. Thank you for the fast response